# How to check if a method is being used in solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net

is there any way to check if a method is being used or referenced anywhere in the solution other that using "Find all references" or searching for that method using Crtl+F.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the problem with the "Find all references"?

Comment: Shift F12 with Resharper to get all Reference across all solution

Comment: Currently, Nope. Also, I've never used it. I'll try that, maybe that might help.

Comment: Requirement: I'm working on an existing solution and I need to make some changes to several methods. I'm not able to find any reference to one of these methods. Hence, this question :)

Comment: As you tagged it as `ASP.NET`: Is it possibly an action in MVC? Because this "references" in views are not detected by VS and you can only find them via text-search.

Comment: R# searches across views too...

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting the method and check if you are getting the Red underlines.